# Same code takes longer if executed more often?

Tags: javascript, iteration, execution-time

I've got the following code inside a `<script>` tag on a webpage with nothing else on it. I'm afraid I do not presently have it online. As you can see, it adds up all primes under two million, in two different ways, and calculates how long it took on average. The variable `howOften` is used to do this a number of times so you can average it out. What puzzles me is, for `howOften == 1`, method 2 is faster, but for `howOften == 10`, method 1 is. The difference is significant and holds even if you hit F5 a couple of times.

My question is simply: how come?

(This post has been edited to incorporate alf's suggestion. But that made no difference! I'm very much puzzled now.)

(Edited again: with `howOften` at or over 1000, the times seem stable. Alf's answer seems correct.)

```
function methodOne(maxN) {
    var sum, primes_inv, i, j;

    sum = 0;
    primes_inv = [];
    for ( var i = 2; i < maxN; ++i ) {
        if ( primes_inv[i] == undefined ) {
            sum += i;
            for ( var j = i; j < maxN; j += i ) {
                primes_inv[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

function methodTwo(maxN) {
    var i, j, p, sum, ps, n;

    n = ((maxN - 2) / 2);
    sum = n * (n + 2);
    ps = [];
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for(j = i; j <= n; j++) {
            p =  i + j + 2 * i * j;
            if(p <= n) {
                if(ps[p] == undefined) {
                    sum -= p * 2 + 1;
                    ps[p] = true;
                }
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return sum + 2;
}



// ---------- parameters
var howOften = 10;
var maxN = 10000;

console.log('iterations: ', howOften);
console.log('maxN: ', maxN);


// ---------- dry runs for warm-up
for( i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
    sum = methodOne(maxN);
    sum = methodTwo(maxN);
}

// ---------- method one
var start = (new Date).getTime();

for( i = 0; i < howOften; i++ )
    sum = methodOne(maxN);

var stop = (new Date).getTime();
console.log('methodOne: ', (stop - start) / howOften);

// ---------- method two

for( i = 0; i < howOften; i++ )
    sum = methodTwo(maxN);

var stop2 = (new Date).getTime();
console.log('methodTwo: ', (stop2 - stop) / howOften);
```

Comment: Method 1 seems to be always faster for me, also when `howOften = 1`: http://jsfiddle.net/KYsGm/. I used 10000 because it took too long otherwise.

Comment: this looks like a big O problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, JS runtime is an optimized JIT compiler. Which means that for a while, your code is interpreted (t<sub>int</sub>), after that, it gets compiled (t<sub>jit</sub>), and finally you run a compiled code (t<sub>run</sub>).

Now what you calculate is most probably (t<sub>int</sub>+t<sub>jit</sub>+t<sub>run</sub>)/N. Given that the only part depending almost-linearly on N is t<sub>run</sub>, this comparison soes not make much sense, unfortunately.

So the answer is, I don't know. To have a proper answer,

1. Extract the code you are trying to profile into functions
2. Run warm-up cycles on these functions, and **do not** use timing from the warm-up cycles
3. Run much more than 1..10 times, both for warm-up and measurement
4. Try swapping the order in which you measure time for algorithms
5. Get into JS interpretator internals if you can and make sure you understand what happens: do you really measure what you think you do? Is JIT run during the warm-up cycles and not while you measure? Etc., etc.

**Update:** note also that for 1 cycle, you get run time less than the resolution of the system timer, which means the mistake is probably bigger than the actual values you compare.

Comment: Very good answer. Makes sense, taught me a lot. Trying it out now!

Comment: Sorry. Tried it, made no difference; see the edited post. Still, not retracting my +1. Again, awesome answer.

Comment: Well, when I increase howOften to over about 1000, that seems to stabilize the measured times.

Comment: `methodOne:  1
methodTwo:  0.7`; `methodOne:  1.5
methodTwo:  0.92`; `methodOne:  1.2271
methodTwo:  0.8257` — it's all relatively stable for me. Google Chrome 16.0.912.75 (Official Build 116452)
OS Mac OS X
WebKit 535.7 (@103989)
JavaScript V8 3.6.6.15

Comment: @toon81 what is your runtime? If it's not the resolution problem, it would be interesting to understand what's going on :)

Comment: My runtime is FF 9 on Linux Mint, which is an Ubuntu derivative. Based on Oneiric, if I'm not mistaken. I've done a few more runs and the difference between 500 and 1000 iterations is significant, but the difference between 1000 and 1500 iterations is not. So I do think you've nailed it.

Comment: iterations: 1000; max: 20000. method one: about 2.3 ms. method two: about 1.2 ms. averaged for 10 runs.

Comment: Well, system timer resolution is usually around 10ms, so I wouldn't count on any value calculated for `howOften` less than 20  :)

Answer (score 0):

methodTwo simply requires that the processor execute fewer calculations.  In methodOne your initial for loop is executing maxN times.  In methodTwo your initial for loop is executing (maxN -2)/2 times.  So in the second method the processor is doing less than half the number of calculations that the first method is doing.  This is compounded by the fact that each method contains a nested for loop.  So big-O of methodOne is maxN^2.  Whereas big-O of methodTwo is ((maxN -2)/2)^2.

Comment: Well, technically they have the same big-O then, don't they... Anyway, the first one's inner loop only executes for the primes. That makes a difference. On the surface, the second one still looks better to me but I can't be certain.

Comment: They don't.  Big-O of n^2 isn't the same as big-O of (n/2)^2.

Comment: Yes, it is. Because an algorithm that takes one million times n^2 has a better big-O than an algorithm that takes one times n^3. Of course, I might be wrong, and I sometimes am. But I don't think I am in this case.

Comment: That's true, but you're talking about the same n here. So, if n = 100, it's either looping 100^2 or 48^2. methodOne.maxN == methodTwo.maxN.

Comment: @TedPrz I believe the point of big-Oh notation is to ignore constants (by definition, *f(x) = O(g(x)) iff exists C > 0, N > 0: for any x > N f(x) < C*g(x)*), so O(n^2) == O((n/2 - 1)^2) == O(C * n^2). We either talk big-Oh or take the coefficients into account, there's no "and" :)

Comment: @alf you're right that constants are irrelevant as n increases, but O(n^2) != O(((n-2)/2)^2).  If you plot the functions f(x) = x^2 and g(x) = ((x-2)/2)^2 on a graph, you'll see that the functions are not the same.   They are only equal when x = 0; and as the value of x grows larger, f(x) increases much more quckly than g(x) does.  Looking specifically at g(x) = (((n-2)/2)^2), there really is no C, because the (n/2) is inside the exponential equation.

Comment: @alf If there was a third equation h(x) = ((x)^2)*10,000 ->then C = 10,000 and C would be increasingly irrelevant as x approached infinity, and we could ignore it.  In fact it doesn't matter how big C is, just as you said.  In the end though, there will always be a material difference between x^2 and (x/2)^2 for a sufficiently large x.  So for a sufficiently large maxN, methodTwo will always run much more quickly than methodOne.

Comment: btw, since this seems like a homework question, I'm dying to know what the professor says on Monday...  :)

Comment: @TedPrz exponential? Pardon me? (n/2 - 1)^2 == 1/4 n^2 - n + 1 == O(1/4 n^2) == O(n^2).

Comment: @alf I think I misspoke when I said "exponential equation".  Nevertheless, the original assignment in methodTwo is:  n = ((maxN - 2) / 2);  Since there are two for loops, one nested inside the other, that each run n times, big-O for methodTwo is n^2 = ((maxN-2)/2)^2.  The thing is, in methodTwo, maxN != n, and I think that's where the mix-up is.  Your initial equation (n/2 -1)^2 is incorrect, because n = ((maxN - 2)/2).  So in the code above, the for loops in methodTwo will always loop slightly less than half the number of times compared to the for loops in methodOne.

Comment: @TedPrz I think you don't really understand what big-Oh means. You're right about method two, but involving a big-Oh notation here is simply incorrect.

Comment: @TedPrz it's not a homework question, it's for project Euler: http://projecteuler.net/problem=10. Me and a friend both came up with a solution and were trying to gauge which of the two was better.

Comment: @toon81 My mistake.  I assumed that you were starting a spring semester data structures class.  My class, at least, began with evaluating the efficiency of code such as the examples you provided.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: @alf I may indeed be wrong, and you may indeed be right.  However, I'm not convinced yet...  My understanding of big-Omega is that it's the worst-case scenario for the time it will take for a computer to execute a given algorithm, or section of code.  It's also useful to compare the big-Oh of two algorithms when trying to determine which will execute more efficiently.  I'm sure it has more applications, but I was taught to use it for exactly this type of problem as a cs undergrad.  Maybe this is where our misunderstanding lies...

Comment: @alf In any case, if you believe that the use of big-Oh here is inappropriate, I'd really appreciate another response as to exactly why.  I'm certainly no expert, I'm here to get better.  But I need proof if I'm going to change my mind...

Comment: @TedPrz big omega, Ω, is a lower bound, to start with. Now, since the definition of big O, Ω, and Θ refer to an arbitrary constant, multiplying by a constant does not mean anything: O(n^2) == O(C2 * n^2 + c1 * n + C0) for *any* C2,C1, C0>0. So comparing big-O for (n/2 -1)^2 and n^2 is senseless. You can indeed use (n/2 -1)^2 and n^2 as an approximation, and be sort of right—but involving Landau notation here is pointless: it eliminates *exactly* what you're trying to compare.